# adding xml innertext with foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, saml

I am trying to add values to the saml:AttributeValue elements of this xml document:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement  xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml:Attribute Name="FNAME">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="LNAME">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="Gender">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="UniqueID">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="DateOfBirth">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="ClientID">
  <saml:AttributeValue></saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

Using this c# code:

```
//get the AttributeStatement node
    XmlNode attrs = assertion.SelectSingleNode("//saml:AttributeStatement", ns1);
//get the Attribute nodes within the AttributeStatement node
            XmlNodeList attr = attrs.SelectNodes("//saml:Attribute", ns1);

//foreach node in the Attribute node list get the AttributeValue node and add an innerText value
            foreach (XmlNode xn in attr)
            {
                XmlNode attrValue = xn.SelectSingleNode("//saml:AttributeValue", ns1);
                switch (xn.Attributes["Name"].Value)
                {
                    case "FNAME":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.FirstName;
                        break;
                    case "LNAME":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.LastName;
                        break;
                    case "Gender":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.Email;
                        break;
                    case "UniqueID":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.UserID.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "DateOfBirth":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.UserID.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "ClientID":
                        attrValue.InnerText = UserInfo.UserID.ToString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        attrValue.InnerText = "No attribute listed";
                        break;
                }
//output each AttributeValue innerText.
                lblTest.Text += attrValue.InnerText + " ";

            }
```

The lblTest is displaying how I would expect - with the correct values for all 6 elements, but the document is not displaying any values at all. Is this the correct way to loop through and add these values to nodes?

Comment: If your xml is in a file then you need to call assertion.Save(filename). If it's a string xml then you need to create a writer and write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the right thing up to a point: the trouble is, you're only updating the in-memory copy of your XML document.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233 for instructions on how to use XmlDocument.Save() to save your in-memory changes down to your XML file.